# Http Binding load balancer

Tags: http, load-balancing

I am hosting a web service on IIS using HTTPS binding. The client and server exchange a lot of messages for the entire duration of the session so it's critical that messages from the same client are routed to the correct server. Will this binding work if I have multiple web servers behind a load balancer?

Does it depend on the technology used by the client? My client app is implemented in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

I use `haproxy` and it allows me to bind requests to a particular backend server using requests source IP.

Another way is to break ssl on the load balances using `stunnel`. 
The connection from the client to the load balancer is encrypted using your original ssl certificate (the client sees no difference), and from the load balancer to the backend using another one (or even not encrypted at all - it depends on your setup). It's kind of a man-in-the-middle, and allows to bind request to a particular backend based on any session id (cookie or almost anything else :) ). Check `haproxy` documentation for details.